# Finding the relative pose between two cameras with 2D and 3D correspondences

Tags: opencv, 3d, computer-vision, pose-estimation

I have two images obtained by a calibrated camera from two different poses. I also have correspondences of 2D points between the images. Some of the points have depth information, so I also know their 3D coordinates. I want to calculate the relative pose between the images.

I know I can compute a fundamental matrix or an essential matrix from the 2D points. I also know PnP can find the pose with 2D-to-3D correspondences and that it's also doable getting just correspondences of 3D points. However, I don't know any algorithm that takes advantage of all the available information. Is there any?

Answer (score 3):

There is only one such algorithm: Bundle Adjustment - everything else is a hack. Get your initial estimates separately, use any "reasonable & simple" hacky way of merging them to get an initial estimate, then byte the bullet and bundle. If you are coding in C++, Google's Ceres is my recommended B.A. library.